# Drawing primitives like line, circle, polygon, nurbs in iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, cross-platform, game-engine

Are there any 3d engines for iOS that have a good set of APIs for drawing primitives such as lines, circle, rectangle, maybe even nurbs?

AFAIK, [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) has a set functions to draw lines and rectangles, but that is it..

Specifically looking for something inside 3d engines so that it is easy to render and visualize 3d models plus provides a mechanism to add primitives to these 3d models on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few 3D game engines. Try using one of them:

1. SIO2 is pretty nice http://sio2interactive.com/
2. Unity3D has iOS support
3. Shiva3D (havent tried it out personally)

Check this [link](http://webification.com/best-iosandroid-cross-platform-mobile-development-sdks) out as well.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I did check out sio2, it requires files of type .sio2 created from  blender..  Unity 3D is not native objective C.. 
Looking for something more native to iOS like ninevehGL or cocos3d.. NinevehGL does not have good touch handling.. I am exploring cocos3d at the moment..